# MSBuild : bin/release folder is not getting created

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I am compiling a solution using below MSBuild script, and Class Library project .dll is getting created in folder obj/Release but dependents project dll is not available there. And Bin\Release folder is also not getting created.

```
<ItemGroup>     
    <PPTProjectToBuild Include="C:\TestProject\sln\Test.sln" />
</ItemGroup>


<MSBuild Projects="@(PPTProjectToBuild)" Properties="Configuration=Release;DebugType=None;DebugSymbols=false;OutputPath=$(PPTCompiledOutputDirPath);ReferencePath=$(ReferencePath)" ContinueOnError="ErrorAndStop"/>
```

Comment: What is the value of the $(PPTCompiledOutputDirPath) variable before MSBuild task is executed?

Comment: Value of $(PPTCompiledOutputDirPath) is C:\PPTTemp. And .dll file created there.  My issue is that why Bin Folder is not getting created for the project. I have three projects in the same solution, Bin folder ris created for other two.

Comment: Because of "OutputPath=$(PPTCompiledOutputDirPath);" part passed to Properties property which tells msbuild and c# compiler where to place the build output.

Comment: So how it is created bin folder for other two projects?

Comment: Are the other two projects included in @(PPTProjectToBuild) projects enumeration?

Comment: Yes that's are included in the @(PPTProjectToBuild)

Comment: ItemGroup should be defined before consuming it by the MSBuild task, if its inside a target.

Comment: @AlexanderPowolozki, in MSBuild script Item Group declared before consuming. Solution file compile successfully, only problem is bin foldet is not getting created.

Comment: And what if when you remove the OutputPath assignment from string passed to Property property in msbuild task?

Comment: Great, its created Bin folder for each project and I have to write a copy command to paste the dll in $(PPTProjectToBuild) path. But still I have confusion why it was creating Bin folder for other project but not for one project?

Comment: For the answer it would be helpfull to see the full build file.

Comment: @"Sujeet Singh" would you mark my answer as helpfull please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass multiple properties to MSBuild task: "Configuration=Release;DebugType=None;DebugSymbols=false;OutputPath=$(PPTCompiledOutputDirPath);ReferencePath=$(ReferencePath)"

Just remove the part "OutputPath=$(PPTCompiledOutputDirPath);" from the properties string and your dlls will be placed into locations configured by each project.

In case you want the build output to be placed somewhere else just set the "OutputPath=" property value to an appropriate location.